# Hi, is there a way to hide recaptcha screen in flutter app that is andoriod,ios?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, hide, recaptcha

<Im trying to hide the  **reCAPTCHA** from the user on my flutter app is there a way to do it??>

Comment: Just remove it from your app alltogether? It's *your* app. You don't have to have it at all.

Comment: im trying to avoid spam on the app  but on the same time need to make the same approach the website do by hiding it with css

Comment: The whole point of a captcha is for the user to see and "answer" it. Maybe you need to eplain yourself in more than one sentence, because your question as written does not make any sense to me. It's like "how do I eat fries without ketchup". Well duh, you don't add ketchup in the first place.